# "Error: ^D" in Windows Git Bash while trying to create a Databricks secret

Tags: bash, git, databricks, git-bash, secret-key

I am trying to create a secret in Databricks in Git Bash. I created a scope, but when I try to enter the secret value I get:

```
$ databricks secrets put-secret $SCOPE $KEYNAME
v Please enter your secret value: 

Error: ^D
```

I am only typing in that first line with the appropriate Scope name and Key name, and then pressing enter, but then that error pops up. Is this just a quirk of git bash? Am I doing it all wrong? I will say that the code databricks has in their [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/security/secrets/example-secret-workflow.html) isn't working for me, which should have been the first sign something was wrong.

Comment: try putting both env vars in dbl-quotes. Also, if you didn't know, some *nix utilities accept/require Ctrl-D (^D) to terminate input. But that doesn't seem to apply here, unless there is a Ctrl-D in your `"$KEYNAME"`. Just some ideas. Good luck.

Comment: I tried the dbl-quotes, but I got the same error. Thank you for your comment though, the tips are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not accidently hit the control-key of your keyboard while entering the secret value? Also, for the safe side (although likely irrelevant here), show the content of `SCOPE` and `KEYNAME`.

Comment: I am absolutely sure I am not hitting the control key at any time in the process. I have tried typing it in multiple times, and every time I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a quirk of Windows git bash. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character for an explanation of ^D. My best guesses would be that you're trying to use ctrl-v on the terminal, which doesn't paste but instead makes the next control code literal ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-V ) and then trying to use ctrl-d ; or one of the files or input streams you're using is empty ; or there's something wrong deep inside how git bash interprets something and you'll never figure it out.

Comment: If there isn't enough information to provide an authoritative, testable answer, better to stick to comments. (If the question as a whole doesn't _allow_ testable answers, either because it's vague or because it's lacking a proper [mre], that's reason to vote to close the question altogether).

Comment: I am not using ctrl-v, but just typing directly into the terminal, but thank you for the quick response. I believe git bash is a deeply flawed program, and its insides will forever be a mystery to me.